# tooltip in canvas in html

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I want to label parts of a brain image using tool-tips. When the cursor rolls over a part name of the brain, the function of the part will be displayed in a tool-tip.

My problem is that the tool-tip is not moving on left side.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        .tooltip {
            position: relative;
            display: inline-block;
            top: 200px;
        }
        .tooltip .tooltiptext {
            visibility: hidden;
            width: 120px;
            background-color: #555;
            color: #fff;
            text-align: center;
            border-radius: 6px;
            padding: 5px 0;
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 1;
            bottom: 125%;
            left: 50%;
            margin-left: -60px;
            opacity: 0;
            transition: opacity 1s;
        }
        .tooltip .tooltiptext::after {
            content: "";
            position: absolute;
            top: 100%;
            left: 50%;
            margin-left: -5px;
            border-width: 5px;
            border-style: solid;
            border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
        }
        .tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
            visibility: visible;
            opacity: 1;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body bgcolor="#008080">

    <body style="text-align:center">
        <div class="tooltip">Genu of Corpus Callosum <span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text </span>
        </div>
        <canvas id="myCanvas" width="900" height="800"></canvas>
        <script>
            var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
            var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
            var imageObj = new Image();
            imageObj.onload = function() {
                context.drawImage(imageObj, 300, 200, 400, 400);
                //doen frontal 1
                context.beginPath();
                context.moveTo(150, 250);
                context.lineTo(450, 250);
                context.stroke();
                //Done
                context.strokeStyle = "white";
                context.beginPath();
                context.moveTo(150, 470);
                context.lineTo(450, 480);
                context.stroke();
                //done
                context.strokeStyle = "white";
                context.beginPath();
                context.moveTo(150, 380);
                context.lineTo(420, 360);
                context.stroke();
                //4done
                context.strokeStyle = "white";
                context.beginPath();
                context.moveTo(80, 530);
                context.lineTo(450, 550);
                context.stroke();
                //3do
                context.strokeStyle = "white";
                context.beginPath();
                context.moveTo(80, 420);
                context.lineTo(380, 400);
                context.stroke();
                //done frontal horn
                context.strokeStyle = "white";
                context.beginPath();
                context.moveTo(800, 300);
                context.lineTo(480, 350);
                context.stroke();
                //gray mattr
                context.strokeStyle = "white";
                context.beginPath();
                context.moveTo(750, 250);
                context.lineTo(560, 300);
                context.stroke();
                //septum 
                context.strokeStyle = "white";
                context.beginPath();
                context.moveTo(850, 350);
                context.lineTo(450, 380);
                context.stroke();
                //putamen
                context.strokeStyle = "white";
                context.beginPath();
                context.moveTo(850, 400);
                context.lineTo(500, 400);
                context.stroke();
                //thalamus
                context.strokeStyle = "white";
                context.beginPath();
                context.moveTo(850, 450);
                context.lineTo(460, 430);
                context.stroke();
                //choroid
                context.strokeStyle = "white";
                context.beginPath();
                context.moveTo(850, 500);
                context.lineTo(460, 450);
                context.stroke();
                //occipital
                context.strokeStyle = "white";
                context.beginPath();
                context.moveTo(850, 550)
                context.lineTo(520, 520);
                context.stroke();
                context.strokeStyle = "white";
                context.beginPath();
                context.moveTo(850, 600)
                context.lineTo(460, 660);
                context.stroke();
            };
            imageObj.src = 'in.jpg';
        </script>

</html>
```

Comment: Show images with current and desired behaviours...

Comment: sorry image is uploading here